# php cURL cookie is not passed

Tags: php, curl, cookies

There is a site, to search for phone numbers. I need to make either a `php script` or a `curl command` to be able to search from a `cron job`.

When I visit the search page, a "session" cookie is created, which is used to obtain the results. On the result page, in case the cookie is missing or it contains wrong information, the search does not yield results.

So I figured I visit the search page, to grab the cookie, then `post` that cookie, alongside the search parameters I need to the result page, which is different (the search page's form action points to that).

The first part is done. I am able to grab the cookie, either parsing the header:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.eofcom.admin.ch/eofcom/public/searchEofcom_InaFree.do');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookiesStringToPass = '';
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
$cookiesStringToPass = '';
foreach ($cookies as $name=>$value) {
    if ($cookiesStringToPass) {
         $cookiesStringToPass  .= ';';
    }
    $cookiesStringToPass .= $name . '=' . addslashes($value);
}
// $cookiesStringToPass now contains the cookie names and values
```

or storing it in a file using:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies.txt');
```

So far so good. Now in the second part, where I need to submit/post the information to obtain the result (again, it's a different page from the search one), should pass the cookie name/value, which is not happening. Either I set explicitly the `cookie` in the `header`, like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.eofcom.admin.ch/eofcom/public/listEofcom_InaFree.do");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Cookie: '.$cookiesStringToPass,
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "nrt=2&pnp=000221&doSearchFreeByNumber=Search");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER , 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

or I set the file generated before:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies.txt');
```

the result is the same: another cookie is generated. Since the values are different, I don't get the result.

Tried to operate in the same session (so without closing the curl connection after the first request), same result. I am aware that the cookie file is not created until the connection is closed, and also, that the order of the `curl_setopt` is important, tried to fiddle with them as well. Still, from a browser it works just fine.

Could someone tell me what's happening? Why the cookie is not set (or ignored?!...)? Even tho it's a `https` request, I am not aware that it would need some kind of certificate or such (in which case probably the request wouldn't return the page, complaining about it...).

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, I've also tried to use

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookiesStringToPass);
```

without success.

---

**Edit 2:** Also tried to rebuild the whole `header`, as it comes from the server, and also tried to include the `referrer`, to no avail.

---

**Edit 3:** From the command line, dumping the header from the search page:

```
curl -v --dump-header headers https://www.eofcom.admin.ch/eofcom/public/searchEofcom_InaFree.do > aa.html
```

and then reusing it to `POST` to the result page

```
curl -v -L -b headers --data "nrt=2&pnp=000991&doSearchFreeByNumber=Search" https://www.eofcom.admin.ch/eofcom/public/listEofcom_InaFree.do > ab.html
```

still produces the same, wrong result, tho this time the cookie is set correctly.

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl, RETURN_TRANSFER,1);` could possibly do it.

Comment: @Robert , already tried that too. `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` actually transfers only the output to a variable. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't related to the cookie. There was a **second session id**, set by javascript on the action of the form, in form of a get parameter. Once passing that too, all worked as expected.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm having the same problem. There is a second session being created somewhere, which I couldn't figure it out how to grab it or find how it is created... could you give me a help? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, give some more details if you haven't figured it out already. We should find another place to talk, SO is not for chat. Or you might want to post a question, and write here the link to it.

Comment: I was able to figure it out! Thanks!